# CData JDBC Driver | java.lang.Exception: Could not find web browser

Tags: java, ubuntu, jdbc, cdata

So I downloaded CData JDBC Driver for Redis from [their official site](https://www.cdata.com/download/getfile.aspx?file=demo/EIRG-V/setup.zip&name=Redis%20JDBC%20Driver&tag=Download-jdbc) and tried to install it on my system. My system is running Ubuntu 20.04 and I have forcefully uninstalled Firefox a long time ago. So while installing the setup, I am getting this error just before the setup is completed:

```
java.lang.Exception: Could not find web browser
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.a.d(Unknown Source)
    at com.izforge.izpack.event.NSInstallerListener.afterPacks(Unknown Source)
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.UnpackerBase.informListeners(Unknown Source)
    at com.izforge.izpack.installer.Unpacker.run(Unknown Source)
```

[image: Error in UI]

I tried installing on my friend's system, running Windows, it was installed successfully, a pop-up with a list of web-browsers was opened redirecting to the Help Web Page.

I tried copy-pasting the folder installed on my friend's system, but it didn't work. I am getting the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: This system contains a license for CData JDBC Driver for Redis 2021 that has been installed but not activated.  You must run setup to activate the license on this system [code: I nodeid: 3TUTFKAF].
    at XcoreXredisX210X7930.tjc.a(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXredisX210X7930.tjc.b(Unknown Source)
    at XcoreXredisX210X7930.jvb.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.cdata.connectors.ConnectorsApplication.main(ConnectorsApplication.java:31)
```

I also tried reinstalling Firefox, but it didn't help. Is there any workaround for this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why exactly do you need a JDBC driver for Redis?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am practicing with Redis before implementing actual connectors for SFDC, Snowflake and Google Analytics.

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't answer why you cannot use official Redis libraries that use TCP rather than JDBC

Comment: @OneCricketeer Because the Task is to implement Connectors using CData JDBC Drivers.

Comment: We are not [CData support](https://www.cdata.com/support/submit.aspx), though

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thanks for the reference to support though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue a while ago. Turns out CData drivers don't support Google Chrome for Linux Systems:

```java
    public static void d(final String s) throws Exception {
        final String property = System.getProperty("os.name");
        if (property.startsWith("Mac OS")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open " + s);
        }
        else if (property.startsWith("Windows")) {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + s);
        }
        else {
            final String[] array = { "firefox", "opera", "konqueror", "epiphany", "mozilla", "netscape" };
            String s2 = null;
            for (int n = 0; n < array.length && s2 == null; ++n) {
                if (Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "which", array[n] }).waitFor() == 0) {
                    s2 = array[n];
                }
            }
            if (s2 == null) {
                throw new Exception("Could not find web browser");
            }
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { s2, s });
        }
    }
```

For the driver to be installed successfully, install Opera or another supported browser from the array using Ubuntu Software App.